# MKS: Find out change package used for updating revision of member

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

I often need to find the change package which was used to "update" or "update revision". I use the following command to find a CP for revision 1.3 of a file:

```
si rlog -r 1.3 --format="{membername}|{memberrev}|{cpid}\n" --noHeaderFormat --noTrailerFormat file_name
```

But this lists only the change package which was used to check in the revision. If the revision was checked in with CP "A" and then a couple days later, set to member revision with CP "B" this command doesn't show the change package number "B".
I can't find a different field than "cpid" in the command line reference. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following cli command you will get all change packages used for updating all revisions of a member:

```
si viewcps --hostname=%Host_name% --port=%port1% --filter=project:%Project%,member:%Member%
```

where `%Project%` is the project/subproject where is located the member and `%Member%` is the name of target member

For more details of this command , call `si viewcps --?`